# Git Credential Manager failing with unsupported browser error

Tags: git, git-for-windows, git-credential-manager

I'm using Git For Windows 2.40.1 on Windows 10 to access a repository on Azure DevOps. It was working fine on Friday, today it's broken.

Any attempt to access the repo launches the Git Credential Manager which prompts me to login, then displays a screen titled "more Information Required", and when I press "Next" it displays another screen with what looks like an embedded browser control telling me my browser is unsupported or out-of-date.

I have the latest Firefox, Chrome and Edge installed and Windows is up-to-date with all updates.

Windows Credential Manager appears to be a component bundled into Git For Windows. There is a bug on their issue tracker stating this issue is fixed

https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/issues/1226

But I've tried versions 2.40.1, 2.40.0 and 2.39.2 of Git For Windows and see the same error in every case.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

[image]

### UPDATE

Tried updating to version 2.1.1 using `dotnet tool update -g git-credential-manager`. That reported that it installed, but didn't seem to replace the active version, so that's useless.

[image]

Also tried manually installing the standalone version from here

https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/releases/tag/v2.0.935

...which according to their documentation is supposed to "forcibly override the version of GCM that is bundled with Git for Windows"

Except that it doesn't

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it decided to stop working all by itself, and none of the online documentation was remotely useful to fix the problem. I was however able to fix it by running `git-credential-manager configure`

[image]

After which everything was working fine again.

Comment: I am having the same issue. How do I install git-credential-manager so that i can use it in the command line? I tried installing the standalone version that you linked in your question but that does not work.

Comment: I can use `git credential-manager configure` and i get the same output in mijn command line as you. But the issue remains the same unfortunately.

Comment: I fixed it. What it did was go to my Azure DevOps and signed out. Then I signed back in and now it worked. I had to do the same steps in Azure DevOps but because i did it in a modern browser i did not get the 'unsupported browser' message. So i could finalize the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I also successfully worked around this issue the same way as Martijn van den Bergh mentioned in his comment. The problem is the git credential manager, even the latest (atm), internally uses an "out-of-date" browser control (IE, I suppose) to display the login flow to the user. For Azure Devops, this suffices for regular logins, but may fail for the onboarding flow if you're connecting for the first time because it may have to run you through extra steps (like installing and configuring MS Authenticator) if the company has a policy that requires you to do so.

I aborted the flow from git, opened a regular "up-to-date" browser and browsed to dev.azure.com/mycompany and was presented with the same flow, but this time I could complete it because the browser I was using was "current". Fully complete the onboarding flow from the browser.

Then afterward, retry from git, and then it worked over there as well.